# How to tar/zip a parent directory exculding a child direcory

Tags: shell, unix, zip, solaris, tar

I want tar a direcory which contains a number of child directories. But here my requirement is to tar the entire parent direcory excuding one child directory.

Is there any command or procedure for this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Tar exclude doesn't exclude why](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/32845/tar-exclude-doesnt-exclude-why)

Answer (score 0):

maybe

tar -zcvf foo_out.tar.gz  --eclude bar foo_dir/

this really belongs in another stackexchange forum.

(from mobile)

Answer (score 0):

Say if the parent directory is called `parent` and the directory to be excluded is `child`, you can try the following:

```
find parent \( ! -wholename "*child*" \) | cpio -ov --format=ustar > outfile.tar
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This One , this creates your tar with excluding some folders or files

tar -czf filename.tar.gz pathToParentFolder  --exclude=pathToParentFolder/childrenFolder